# ckeditor - can't disable advanced content filter

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ckeditor

CKEditor is nice but it strips away all html tags and css. It's because of their new advanced content filter. It's ruining all of my webpage layout.

I tried disabling it in `config.js` but it doesn't make any difference, I've been messing with this all day and have tried many variations on the following code. Can anyone spot any obvious errors in `config.js`

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.allowedContent = true;  

    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for a single toolbar row.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
    ];

    // The default plugins included in the basic setup define some buttons that
    // we don't want too have in a basic editor. We remove them here.
    config.removeButtons = 'Cut,Copy,Paste,Undo,Redo,Anchor,Underline,Strike,About,Others,Forms';

    // Let's have it basic on dialogs as well.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised the problem was not CKEditor. I was passing the data through `htmlentities()` and `striptags()` in PHP which was removing all the markup. I now only have `mysql_escape_string()` checking the data. Is there any more functions I can use to sanitize the data without messing up the layout?